# Incompatible pointer type assigning to NSDate* from NSDate*?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

This a bit wired warning I get. I defined a NSDate like this in header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *selected;
```

Later in .m file I try to get the date chose by date picker:

```
self.selected = [_datePicker date];
```

Definition of date picker:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

Both are same type NSDate*. Why do I get this warning?

Comment: If you would copy the **actual** error message instead of rephrasing the error, the mistake would have been even more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) and [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/) are quite different!

Comment: Gush I made a silly mistake.